# Lenovo T490 shutdown at idle

Tags: shutdown

I have a Lenovo T490 with Windows 10 (20H2 Build: 19042.685). I notice that if I leave it on for a while and when it tries to go into sleep mode, it will force shutdown by itself. Below is the event log.

[image: Windows Event Log]

I have tried updating all the Windows 10 updates, drivers (graphics, power etc) but still having the issue.

The only workaround is to disable the sleep setting.

Also, I noticed that if I shut the lid, it will go into sleep without shutting down.

Answer (score 0):

Best workaround for this is to disable "turn off display" and only enable "sleep" mode after a certain period.

I suspect there is a problem either in System BIOS or Graphic Card Driver since the shutdown only happens after display is turned off. I have updated to latest BIOS and Graphic Driver but the issue still persists.